# "Add button in toolbar" checkbox: which toolbar?

Tags: qgis-3

When I go in the Processing Settings, under Menus, select an item, check "Add button in toolbar" and click OK, I don't see anything happening. I enabled all toolbars under View > Toolbar and still can't find the item I just added.

Where is it ?

I'm on QGIS 3.6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:
First, it's the "Processing Algorithms" toolbar and second, I had to restart QGIS for the changes to take effect.